# How can I undo syncing a branch to the mainline?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Until now I have used bitbucket for repo, and until a few days I found this feature that says SYNC in the branch I was using. This feature from what I understood puts me up to date with master. The thing I did not know is every time I git pulled master, it pulled the branch also. I thought it only updated the branch without affecting the master, but somehow if I pulled from master, i had the changes made in the branch.

How can I undo this event, so that when I pull master, I don't end up also pulling that branch?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the situation you're describing here. Can you make it clearer what you mean by "pull the branch also" for instance, like explaining which branches it pulls from and which ones it merges into, what you want it to do, and how that differ from what it currently apparently does?

Comment: That sounds like a normal fast forward commit.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language. I found this button that says sync on bitbucket, so I pressed it.. thinking it will only update branch, not master. What happened is that it merged master into branch, so everytime I pulled master, it also pulled the changes in branch.

Comment: Master *is* a branch. Master is the name of the primary branch in a repo, by convention.

Comment: I pressed the SYNC button on Bitbucket, now everytime I make a pull from master, I get that branch... which has lots of bugs